# Yii2 jui datepicker как установить placeholder?

Tags: yii2, datepicker

Yii2 jui datepicker как установить placeholder? Собственно этого мне и не хватает. 
 А ещё лучше чтоб текущая дата выводилась значением по-умолчанию.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
                        'language' => 'ru',
                        'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
                        'class' => '6u$ 12u$(mobile)',
                ])->label(false)?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$form->field($model,'birthday')->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),['clientOptions' => ['dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy']])->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Я плейсхолдер']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo DateTimePicker::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'date_exam',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Текст плейсхолдера здесь ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii'
        ]
    ]);
```